# Is Imperial County, California the most pro Bernie Sanders county in America that is less than 50% white?

Tags: united-states, demographics, bernie-sanders, democratic-primary

In the 2020 Democratic primary, I was looking at Texas's southern counties because I knew that they were the most heavily Latino in the country and Latinos are the demographic that is the most likely to support Bernie Sanders. Starr stood out to me. It gave 41.6% of the vote to Bernie Sanders. I believe that this is unmatched in any other place that is majority-minority.

However, I looked at California's majority Latino counties. I found Imperial. It gave 43.6% of the vote to him. Is this analysis correct?

Comment: Why all this emphasis on the race of voters? Aren't we supposed to NOT look at the color of one's skin?!

Comment: We are not exactly looking at the color of skin. For example, I am white and Hispanic at the same time. This is because voters of different RACES (not just colors) tend to vote differently in America.

Comment: @Sjoerd No, "colorblindness" is not longer advocated for on the left, and was never advocated for by POC.

Comment: I agree. I am both of those things (they go hand in hand where I'm from) and do not advocate colorblindness

Answer (score 1):

No - Rolette County, North Dakota's population is [around](https://datausa.io/profile/geo/rolette-county-nd#:~:text=The%20ethnic%20composition%20of%20the,Alone%20residents%20(0.45%25)%2C%2049) 18% White Alone, and the Democratic caucus which [took place](https://elections.ap.org/dailykos/results/2020-03-10/state/ND/race/P/raceid/35321) in Belcourt, Rolette County gave Sanders 64.71% of the vote.